# Grails: How to buffer outbound emails when SMTP server is temporarely down?

Tags: email, grails, asynchronous, smtp

Grails uses mailService from Spring. That service is synchronous, which means if SMTP goes down temporarily, application functioning is affected badly (HTTP 500).

I want to decouple the application from SMTP server.

The plan is to save ready-to-be-sent emails into an outbound queue and send them by timer, with retries. For my own code, when I call mailService directly, it is rather trivial - make a wrapper service and call it instead. But some of the plugins that my application uses (e.g. EmailConfirmation plugin) use the same mailService, and still fail, effectively blocking sign-up process, for instance.

I wonder how can I replace/wrap the definition of mailService to make all code, my own and plugins, transparently use my own service?

I.e.

- Plugin code injects mailService
- But instead of Spring default mailService my own code is injected
- When plugin sends a email the email object is saved to DB instead
- On timer a job wakes up, gets next N emails and tries to send them

Any ideas how to approach this problem?

P.S. I know about AsynchronousMail plugin. Unfortunately, its service must be called explicitely, i.e. it is not a drop-in replacement for mailService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it wasn't that hard, after all. Easy steps first:

**Step one**: prepare database table to store pending email records:

```
class PendingEmail {
    Date sentAt = new Date()
    String fileName

    static constraints = {
        sentAt nullable: false
        fileName nullable: false, blank:false
    }
}
```

**Step two**: create a periodic task to send the pending emails. Note `mailSender` injection - it is part of original Grails Mail Plugin, so the sending (and configuration of it!) is made via Mail Plugin:

```
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage

class BackgroundEmailSenderJob {

    def concurrent = false
    def mailSender

    static triggers = {
        simple startDelay:15000l, repeatInterval: 30000l, name: "Background Email Sender"
    }

    def execute(context){
        log.debug("sending pending emails via ${mailSender}")

        // 100 at a time only
        PendingEmail.list(max:100,sort:"sentAt",order:"asc").each { pe ->

            // FIXME: do in transaction
            try {
                log.info("email ${pe.id} is to be sent")

                // try to send
                MimeMessage mm = mailSender.createMimeMessage(new FileInputStream(pe.fileName))
                mailSender.send(mm)

                // delete message
                log.info("email ${pe.id} has been sent, deleting the record")
                pe.delete(flush:true)

                // delete file too
                new File(pe.fileName).delete();
            } catch( Exception ex ) {
                log.error(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Step three**: create a drop-in replacement of mailService that could be used by any Grails code, including plugins. Note mmbf injection: this is `mailMessageBuilderFactory` from Mail Plugin. The service uses the factory to serialize the incoming Closure calls into a valid MIME message, and then save it to the file system:

```
import java.io.File;

import org.springframework.mail.MailMessage
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMailMessage

class MyMailService {
    def mmbf

    MailMessage sendMail(Closure callable) {
        log.info("sending mail using ${mmbf}")

        if (isDisabled()) {
            log.warn("No mail is going to be sent; mailing disabled")
            return
        } 

        def messageBuilder = mmbf.createBuilder(mailConfig)
        callable.delegate = messageBuilder
        callable.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
        callable.call()
        def m = messageBuilder.finishMessage()

        if( m instanceof MimeMailMessage ) {
            def fil = File.createTempFile("mail", ".mime")
            log.debug("writing content to ${fil.name}")
            m.mimeMessage.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(fil))

            def pe = new PendingEmail(fileName: fil.absolutePath)
            assert pe.save(flush:true)
            log.debug("message saved for sending later: id ${pe.id}")
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("expected MIME")
        }
    }

    def getMailConfig() {
        org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder.config.grails.mail
    }

    boolean isDisabled() {
        mailConfig.disabled
    }
}
```

**Step four**: replace Mail Plugin's mailService with the modified version, injecting it with the factory. In `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`:

```
beans = {
    mailService(MyMailService) {
        mmbf = ref("mailMessageBuilderFactory")
    }
}
```

Done!

From now on, any plugin or Grails code that uses/injects mailService will get a reference to MyMailService. The service will take requests to send the email, but instead of sending it it will serialize it onto disk, saving a record into database. A periodic task will load a bunch of such records every 30s and try to send them using the original Mail Plugin services.

I have tested it, and it seems to work OK. I need to do cleanup here and there, add transactional scope around sending, make parameters configurable and so on, but the skeleton is a workable code already.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Yah, I think code is going to help me, thanks, as I deploy my web application to a linux hosting environment.  Can I ask you, what you decided for the SMTP server.  Did you find anything simple and light .. does it run on your server?

Comment: SMTP I develop on is postfix running on my dev box; SMTP in PROD is the one used by my hosting company. I care not what they run (I believe it is qmail, but may be mistaken).

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution for this is using a locally installed mail server. There are the well known and full blown MTAs  like Postfix, Sendmail or Exim available as well as lightweight replacements like http://packages.qa.debian.org/s/ssmtp.html.

Configure the used MTA package to relay all its emails to the real SMTP server of your domain. The Grails application would then simply use 127.0.0.1 as SMTP host.

This has also the advantage of improved response time in your application, since email sending no longer requires any non-local IP traffic in first place.

Comment: Good point. Except local MTA could be down too. Ultimate goal is to decouple application from external services.

Comment: agreed, but MTAs are mostly rock solid, for years I've never observed e.g. a postfix going down.

Comment: It is just not in every environment developer could decide where MTA is installed. Even rock-solid and local MTA can go down sometimes due to operational personnel mistake or, e.g., upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

The Asynchronous mail plugin now supports overriding the mail plugin
Just add

```
asynchronous.mail.override=true
```

to your config.  See http://grails.org/plugin/asynchronous-mail

Comment: Thanks! One year late, but better late than never.